# When do stochastic maps agree?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

For integers $p,q >0$ let $M$ and $N$ be $q \times p$ matrices of non-negative reals which have each of their columns summing to $1.$

We can think of $M$ describing a stochastic map sending points $\{1,..,p\}$ to probability distributions over $\{1,..,q\}$ (where $M_{i,j}$ gives the probability of $i$ occurring in the probability distribution $j$ gets sent to).

Let us define *the solution set* $S$ be the set of vectors ${\bf x}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_p \end{pmatrix}\; \in \mathbb{R}^p$ satisfying the following three conditions:

- $x_i \geq 0$ for each $i \in \{1,..,p\}$
- $\sum_{i=1} ^p x_i =1.$
- $M {\bf x} = N {\bf x}.$

Basically $S$ is the set of distributions that are "mapped the same way" under $M$ and $N.$

The question is, does there always exist an integer $n$ such that $S$ is an $n$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) ?

In other words, does there exist integer $n$ and affinely independent points ${\bf y}_0,{\bf y}_1,..,{\bf y}_n \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $S$ is the convex hull of $\{{\bf y}_0,{\bf y}_1,..,{\bf y}_n \}.$ ?

Here we shall say that the empty set is an $n$-simplex for $n=-1,$ so the case where $S$ is empty also counts as "simplex shaped". The question is whether $S$ is always simplex shaped.

The question essentially corresponds to the question of whether the Klieisli category of the distribution monad has all equalizers, but I imagine there is no need to think about category theory to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, in general, no.

Consider a 4-element set $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and a 2-element set $X=\{x,y\}$. Consider now the following functions $f,g:A\to X$ as follows.

- $f(a)=f(b)=x$,
- $f(c)=f(d)=y$;
- $g(a)=g(b)=y$,
- $g(c)=g(d)=x$.

In other words, the two functions differ by a permutation of $X$.
First of all we see that on no point of $A$ do the functions agree. (In terms of category theory, their equalizer in the category of sets is the empty set.)

Let's now pass to stochastic matrices and simplices.
The maps $f$ and $g$ induce "deterministic" stochastic maps (i.e. of entries only zero and one), or in terms of category theory, you can apply to $f$ and $g$ the "simplex" functor, and obtain two maps from a tetrahedron (=simplex with 4 vertices) to a segment (=simplex with 2 vertices).

As you can see, their equalizer is a *square* subset of the tetrahedron, as in the image below, where the two vertices above the square are $a$ and $b$ and the ones below are $c$ and $d$.
So this equalizer is not a simplex. (In terms of category theory, it is a [convex space](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5522), but not a *free* one.)

In terms of equation, it is the subset of the simplex where $p(a)+p(b)=p(c)+p(d)=1/2$.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the illuminating counter example

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ and $N$ are randomly generated such that their columns sum to 1, it's equivalent to generating random stochastic matrices. The difference of two stochastic matrices, $M - N$, will not necessarily be a stochastic matrix, and the null space of $M - N$ won't necessarily contain stochastic vectors.

The constraints on the linear program you're trying to solve are essentially looking for a linear combination of the vectors in the kernel that is also a stochastic vector (nonnegative components, components sum to 1). This might not always be possible.

For example, consider a simple case where $p=q=2$, and $M$ and $N$ are such that $M - N$ has a single nonzero row. The null space of $M - N$ will be a line in 2D space, and the only stochastic vector on this line will be the one that lies on the positive segment of the line between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. If this vector is not in the null space, then there will be no solution to the problem.

In conclusion, it's possible that there are no stochastic vectors in the affine space spanned by the kernel of $M - N$, depending on the specific $M$ and $N$. This could explain why brute forcing the problem [I tried] doesn't seem to give solutions after $\approx 5\times 10^6$ iterations.

Comment: I mean, there are cases where S is empty. Like when p=q=2 and M sends each input to 1 to probability 1, while N sends all inputs to  2, with probability 1. But I mean, in the case where S is empty, can't we still say that S is an n-simplex for n=-1. In other words S is the free convex set generated by the empty set. I'm wondering if there is a case where S is non-empty but not a simplex. Is the jury still out on that ?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it clearer than I consider the empty set simplex shaped